# Is there an electromechanical equivalent of an SPDT switch?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, switches, toggle-switch, electro-mechanical

I want to control 2 outputs with a single input. SPDT switches are mechanical from what I understand, is there an equivalent of electromechanical switches like SSR for SPDT for example?

Comment: Yes, such things exist in many forms. Can you please be more specific about your inputs and outputs? Are they digital signals? What voltage, frequency, current? Uni or bidirectional? Or analog - voltage, current, noise requirements? These are important details in selecting a suitable component.

Comment: SPDT is contact configuration that can be applied to many kinds of mechanical, electromechanical and electronic devices. So, the short answer to your question is "Yes". The long answer is that the short answer is probably useless without knowing more about specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @hello_world07. This question has been answered a few months ago and you should be able to search for an existing answer ...

Comment: Polarized relay may suit you.

Comment: An SSR is *not* electromechanical; it's electronic. That's the whole point of making it solid-state. Do you want something electromechanical, or something electronic?

Comment: What voltage and current?

Answer (score 3):

An SPDT relay or SPDT contactor. The same terminology applies.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent would be an SPDT Mosfet Relay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are SPDT SSRs. For example, a [search for SPDT SSRs on Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/solid-state-relays/183?s=N4IgjCBcpgzADFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWeAVgE4A2OkAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfaUA) currently returns 17 results (though some of these are variations of the same SSR). However, SPDT SSRs are very rare compared to SPST SSRs -- [a search on Digikey for SPST-NO SSRs](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/solid-state-relays/183?s=N4IgjCBcpgzADFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWeANhvgHYQBdIgBwBcoQBlDgJwCWAOwDmIAL5SgA) currently returns 7,188 results (and there are SPST-NC SSRs, too). Given the limited selection and your requirements you may need to build your own SPDT equivalent out of two SPST SSRs and external logic to turn on only one of them at a time.

Depending on your requirements you may also be able to use an "analog switch", which is an integrated circuit that comes in a variety of configurations, including SPDT (often with multiple SPDT switches per IC). These are not as rare as SPDT SSRs -- a [search on Digikey for SPDT analog switches](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/interface-analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAbABiqAxlAZgQwDYGcBTAGhAHsoBtEAFgHYBmee%2BkE6xAVgVpAF0SADgBcoIAMpCATgEsAdgHMQAXyUkATJRBZZuUvIAEeAO7ShqABZ8lQA) currently returns 2,085 results.